# How to fix import error "Module not found: Can't resolve './components'" - using Named Exports

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, importerror, react-leaflet

I am attempting to create a [React-Leaflet map](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) setup with create-react-app, but I am unable to import my [Simple-Map](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/simple.js) component, which is exported using [Named Exports](https://codecubed.io/blog/named-export-vs-default-export). This is the first example on the [React-Leaflet Examples](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/examples) page.

The error is:

```
./src/Simple.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components' in '/ice_map/src'
```

The [import statement](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/simple.js#L4) from the example has been changed to `import {Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from './components'` to reflect actual location of file.

The components directory contains 4 files: Map.js, TileLayer.js, Marker.js, Popup.js

The rest of the `Simple.js` file has been left as in the example. This file is imported into `App.js` via `import SimpleExample from './Simple'`

I understand this is a simple issue and an error that I am making, however I have not been able to resolve this error.

Any input is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

In case this helps, here is my folder structure in VS code.
[image: directory hierarchy]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok if you can try to add index.js file in the components folder

and inside it, you will add these

```
import Map from './Map';
import  Marder from './Marder';
import  Popup from './Popup';
import TileLayer from './TileLayer';


module.exports = {Map, Marder, Popup, TileLayer};
```

and you must ensure you are export these files `Map, Marder, Popup, TileLayer`

and that's because when you import from the folder you already import index file and there didn't find it

```
import <somting> from './components' === import <somting> from './components/index'
```

or you try use this

```
import Map from './components/Map';
import Marder from './components/Marder'; 
import Popup from './components/Popup'; 
import TileLayer from './components/TileLayer';
```

and delete this

```
import {Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from './components'
```

Comment: Thank you Hassan, adding the `index.js` has made the error message dissapear. I am however not getting a map yet (could be separate issue) and I have a console error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'``` in ```main.chunk.js:256```

... --> When you say to export these files ```Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer``` are you referring to the module.exports statement in your reply or another export statement elsewhere?

Comment: You're welcome if you have any problem ask me
and I Will try to help you

Comment: Yes Hassan sorry, do you anticipate that the syntax error is coming from bad html or JS? I haven't made changes from the example on React-Leaflet so I wonder where I could start looking for this? Also: should I be exporting Map, .. , etc somewhere else? I have exports in the original file and the export statement in `index.js` as you have above ... && thank you!!

Comment: try use this 
```
import Map from './components/Map';
import  Marder from './components/Marder';
import  Popup from './components/Popup';
import TileLayer from './components/TileLayer';
```
and delete the
```
import {Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from './components'
```